# Would this be a good anti sql injection function?

Tags: php, sql, function, code-injection

Currently I use this function as a countermeasure for my website just wondering if it can effectively block SQL injections. Since I tested my website with Accunetix WPS, ZAP and NetSparker of which only ZAP said my website was vulnerable to injections of the `type = 'ZAP'` or `'1=1'`.

Should I worry?

```
function anti_injection($sql){
   $sql = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$sql);
   $sql = trim($sql);
   $sql = strip_tags($sql);
   $sql = addslashes($sql);
   if($mysqlsupport == 1)
   {
   $sql = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
   }
   return $sql;
 }
```

Comment: you can also use `settype()` function or `sprintf()` to force type conversions. check here more details here http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: No, don't do this. The nested stripping/escaping is particularly wrong - you should use the right tool for the job. [Read this](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: Why not simply switch to mysqli or pdo with prepared statements/bind variables, and this would be a non-issue.... far better than preventing your English-speaking users from using common English words in text

Comment: Is there a requirement in your project to not use something more modern and safer such as prepared queries, PDO, etc?

Comment: @halfer how should I format these?

Comment: @Phate01: brand names and programming languages and technology names can be treated as [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun). An initial capital letter, or all-caps for acronyms, is fine.

Comment: I have to useMSSQL so mysql is a no go. What couls i change to make it a good anti sql function?

Comment: MsSql doesn't preclude using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

Comment: But if you `have to use MSSQL so mysql is a no go` why does your code include `if($mysqlsupport == 1)
   {
   $sql = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
   }
`?

Comment: Thats an statrment i made at the time that i didnt know which one i would end up using but when i tried to switch to mysql it emded up ruining everythibg.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**: No, this would not be a good anti sql injection function.

There are many many tools that work, and work well, so we as developers don't need to try to cover every edge when it comes to protecting our databases.

Please look into, at the very least, PDO.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php